# How to fill a linked list with elements I already have?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list with elements I have, but I need 24 nodes for this and I don't want to end up like this:

```
head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->id = 1;
```

How can I prevent this?

I tried creating something likes but all nodes(obviously) are pointing the same data.

```
void init_board(block **head)
{
    block temp;

    temp.id=0;
    temp.name="Start";
    temp.price=0;
    temp.rent=0;
    temp.next = NULL;

    *head = &temp;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
    (*head)->next = (block*) malloc(sizeof(block*));
    temp = head->next;

    temp.id=1;
    temp.name="End";
    temp.price=16000;
    temp.rent=800;
    temp.next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to create a linked list with elements I have, but I need 24 nodes for this and I don't want to end up like this:
>
> head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->id = 1;
> How can I prevent this?

updating *head* (not only `*head`)

> ```
>  block temp;
>  ...
>  temp = head->next;
> ```

you cannot do that, because *temp* is s *struct* but *next* a pointer

> I tried creating something likes but all nodes(obviously) are pointing the same data.

you need to allocate a new cell for all the new element, including for the first you currently put in the stack (**never** return the address of something saved in the stack)

> (*head)->next = (block*) malloc(sizeof(block*));

this is not what you want, you need to alloc for a *block*, not for a *block **

Example initializing with two cells :

```
void init_board(block **plast)
{
  *plast = malloc(sizeof(block));
  (*plast)->id=0;
  (*plast)->name="Start";
  (*plast)->price=0;
  (*plast)->rent=0;
  (*plast)->next = malloc(sizeof(block));
  plast = &(*plast)->next;
  (*plast)->id=1;
  (*plast)->name="End";
  (*plast)->price=16000;
  (*plast)->rent=800;
  (*plast)->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
   block * l;

   init_board(&l);
}
```

---

Of course if you have 20 block to initialize to expanse each case is not practical, may be the values come from a file or an array like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct block {
  int id;
  const char * name;
  int price;
  int rent;
  struct block * next;
} block;

const block Boards[] = {
  { 0, "Start", 0, 0, NULL },
  { 2, "Intermediate", 123, 456, NULL },
  { 1, "End", 16000, 800, NULL }
};

void init_board(block **plast)
{
  for (const block * b = Boards; b != Boards + sizeof(Boards)/sizeof(Boards[0]); ++b) {
    *plast = malloc(sizeof(block));
  
    (*plast)->id = b->id;
    (*plast)->name = b->name;
    (*plast)->price = b->price;
    (*plast)->rent = b->rent;
    (*plast)->next = NULL;
    plast = &(*plast)->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  block * blocks;
  
  init_board(&blocks);
  
  /* debug */
  for (block * b = blocks; b != NULL; b = b->next)
    printf("%d %s %d %d\n", b->id, b->name, b->price, b->rent);
  
  /* free resources */
  while (blocks != NULL) {
    block * b = blocks;
    
    blocks = blocks->next;
    free(b);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall l.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0 Start 0 0
2 Intermediate 123 456
1 End 16000 800
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6819== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6819== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6819== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6819== Command: ./a.out
==6819== 
0 Start 0 0
2 Intermediate 123 456
1 End 16000 800
==6819== 
==6819== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6819==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6819==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 1,084 bytes allocated
==6819== 
==6819== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6819== 
==6819== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6819== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I tried various things before asking so my code was bit off. I was stuck with the idea using "temp" but that just made things complicated for me. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MertcanElçi You welcome. I edited my answer for more inputs

Comment: "`head = &(*head)->next;`" um wat? :D that is devious.

Comment: you've overridden the meaning of `head` there. Just use `block *current = *head = malloc(..)` once and `current` on all following lines instead of `*head`. It is also easier to read and slightly more performant because now the compiler need not check if the malloc changed the `head` pointer or something.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work nicely with the for loop though.

Comment: It says 

```test.c:318:25: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘block {aka struct block}’)
     current = &(*current)->next; ```

btw

Comment: @MertcanElçi probably you did `block * current;` rather than `block ** current;` Look at my code ;-)

Comment: @MertcanElçi If you want to follow Antti Haapala proposal using a simple pointer  dereference one times rather than two. But warning, do not forget to modify the `*head` (making the first added element a special case)

Comment: Oh sorry @bruno I didn't see you changed the function argument too. It works now :)

Comment: @MertcanElçi I only changed its name, not its type. Is ok, happy coding

Answer (score -1):

```
struct link 
{
  int data;
  int dataOne;
  // data n....
   struct link* link;
};
// HeadNode
struct link* pHeadLink = NULL;
//add the link and return the current.
struct link* appendLink()
{
   if(pHeadLink == NULL)
   {
     pHeadLink = (struct link*) malloc(sizeof(struct link));
     pHeadLink->link = NULL;
     return pHeadLink;
  }
  struct link *pTempLink = pHeadLink;
  while(pTempLink->link != NULL)
  {
     pTempLink = pTempLink->link;
  }
  pTempLink->link = (struct link*) malloc(sizeof(struct link));
  pTempLink->link->link = NULL;
  return pTempLink;
}
// calling function:
int fun()
{

 loop() // loop for 24 times. 
{ 
  struct link* pFillDataLink = appendLink();
   // here you can fill rest the items like below.
   pFillDataLink->data = 34;
   pFillDataLink->dataOne = 334; 
   // etc.... 
}
}
```